# ¿Como acceder a un foreach en php?

Tags: php, foreach

Hola buenas me gustaría saber como acceder a cada elemento obtenido de un foreach

```
foreach($_REQUEST["Ejemplo"] as $valor){
    echo $valor . "<br />";
}
```

Imaginaros que el resultado mostrado por pantalla es:

1 
2 
3

Yo lo que quiero es por ejemplo coger el 2 y dejar el 1 y el 3 en un for es fácil por posición pero en un foreach, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Lo que debes hacer es si buscas el dos, es comparar la variable $valor contra dos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recuerda que el forearch tambien se maneja como clave valor, lo que veo tienes un recorrido simple puede usar el el forearch de la siguiente manera.

```
foreach($_REQUEST["Ejemplo"] as $posicion= >$valor){
  echo "la posicion es:".$position."El valor es:".$valor . ";

}
```

Te dejo un Ejemplo

```
<?php 
$frutas = array(manzana=>'Roja', banana=>'Amarillo', aguacate=>'Verde');

foreach($frutas as $fruta => $color){
    if ($fruta == 'manzana'){
        echo "La " . $fruta . " es " . $color;
    }   
}
?>
```